# Why does subshell background process not exit on parent process SIGINT?

Tags: bash

I have the following script `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

function cleanup() {
    echo "calling cleanup"
    echo "PIDs associated with $0"
    ps aux | grep $0
    echo "killing $$ $(jobs -p)"

    kill $(jobs -p | xargs)
    exit 0
}

function subshell() (
    echo "subshell pid $BASHPID"
    while true
    do
        echo "subshell running..."
        sleep 5
    done
)

function no_subshell() {
    echo "no_subshell pid $BASHPID"
    while true
    do
        echo "no_subshell running..."
        sleep 10
    done
}

# Main
echo "test.sh pid $$"
trap "exit" INT TERM SIGUSR1
trap cleanup EXIT

subshell &
no_subshell &
echo "Waiting..."
jobs -l
wait
```

My expectation is that if SIGINT is called on the parent process, `test.sh`, that both `subshell` and `no_subshell` functions should be cleaned up as well.  However, in practice, this is what I observe:

```
./test.sh

test.sh pid 49199
Waiting...
[1]- 49200 Running                 subshell &
[2]+ 49201 Running                 no_subshell &
no_subshell pid 49201
no_subshell running...
subshell pid 49202
subshell running...
^Ccalling cleanup
PIDs associated with ./test.sh
root     49199  0.0  0.0 106144  2896 pts/1    S+   03:43   0:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
root     49200  0.0  0.0 106144   232 pts/1    S+   03:43   0:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
root     49201  0.0  0.0 106144  2248 pts/1    S+   03:43   0:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
root     49202  0.0  0.0 106144  2248 pts/1    S+   03:43   0:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
root     49206  0.0  0.0 103488  2184 pts/1    S+   03:43   0:00 grep ./test.sh
killing 49199 49200
49201
```

After SIGINT, the `subshell` function continues to run under PID 49202 which is NOT listed by `jobs -l` in my `cleanup` function:

```
px aux | grep test
root     49202  0.0  0.0 106144  2248 pts/1    S    03:43   0:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
```

Also, it looks like the subshell function was tracked by PID 49200 which is reported by `jobs -p`, and also (presumably killed), but the subshell function seems to live on in PID  49202.

What explains this behavior that I'm observing?  And how do I get `test.sh` to also clean up subshell functions that were run in the background?

Answer (score 1):

The command kill does kill a process only if it belongs in the same process group (PPID). Your program PPID seems to be 2896, but the subshell and no_subshell PPID is 2248.

Comment: I've confirmed that everything spawned from `test.sh` is in the same PGID.  Something about `jobs -p` doesn't get everything in the PGID so the devil seems to be in that details.